# Exclude directories in a List Comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, macos, list-comprehension

I want to get a list of all picture files in a directory, excluding certain subdirectories.

I have a List Comprehension I normally use to extract files, which works, but includes subdirectories I do not want.

> This is on `macOS` and 'Photos Library.photoslibrary' is "package".The contents are normally hidden by the OS and the library appears to the user as a file, but to `Unix` this is just a normal directory which contains a massive number of files.

I have attempted to exclude the directory, as `os.walk()` describes, but my attempts all produce syntax errors.

```
the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
    (e.g., via del or slice assignment), and walk will only recurse into the
    subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames
```

Is it possible to exclude within a List Comprehension

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os

pdir = "/Users/ian/Pictures"

def get_files(top, extension=".jpg"):
    """
    For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top,
    return all files which match extension.

    """
    files = [os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top)
#         if 'Photos Library.photoslibrary' in dirnames:
#             dirnames.remove('Photos Library.photoslibrary')
        for filename in filenames
        if filename.endswith(extension)
        if 'Photos Library.photoslibrary' in dirnames:
            dirnames.remove('Photos Library.photoslibrary')
        ]
    return files

for file in get_files(pdir, (".JPG", ".JPEG", ".jpg", ".jpeg")):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get a `List Comprehension` to work, so I modified the code to a `Generator Function`, and make a List from the result.
The code below works.

```
def get_files(top, exclude=None, extension=".jpg"):
    """
    For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top,
    return all files which match extension.
    exclude is an optional string or tuple/list of strings
        to exclude named subdirectories.
    """
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
        if(exclude is not None):
            if(type(exclude) == str):   # prevent Python treating str as sequence
                if exclude in dirnames:
                    dirnames.remove(exclude)
            else:
                for excl in exclude:
                    if excl in dirnames:
                        dirnames.remove(excl)
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(extension):
                yield(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

for file in get_files(pdir, ('Photos Library.photoslibrary', 'iPhoto Library.photolibrary'), (".JPG", ".JPEG", ".jpg", ".jpeg")):
    print(file)
```

The `type` test for exclude is inelegant, but Python polymorphism otherwise misinterprets strings,